# CentOS 7 Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64 When yum update

Tags: centos-7, yum

This error is driving me crazy, I have been trying everything posted in the forums and nothing works.

When I Type:

`# yum update`

I get the following error:

> [root@www yum.repos.d]# yum update Complementos cargados:fastestmirror
>   Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile Could not retrieve
>   mirrorlist
>   http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock
>   error was 14: curl#56 - "Recv failure: Connection reset by remote
>   machine"
>
> One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),  and yum doesn't
>   have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only  safe
>   thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:
>
> ```
>  1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.
>
>  2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
>     upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
>     distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
>     packages for the previous distribution release still work).
>
>  3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
>         yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...
>
>  4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
>     will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
>     again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:
>
>         yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
>     or
>         subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>
>
>  5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
>     Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
>     so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
>     slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
>     compromise:
>
>         yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
> ```
>
> Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64

It is a production server with its own IP, so I haven't tried that DHCP on and ONBOOT=no (I have it in yes), etc.

If i type:

`# curl -v 'http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?repo=os&arch=x86_64&release=7'`

This is what I get:

```
[root@www yum.repos.d]# curl -v 'http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?repo=os&arch=x86_64&release=7'
* About to connect() to mirrorlist.centos.org port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 2001:1b48:203::4:10...
* Connected to mirrorlist.centos.org (2001:1b48:203::4:10) port 80 (#0)
> GET /?repo=os&arch=x86_64&release=7 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: mirrorlist.centos.org
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection reset by remote machine
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by remote machine
```

Contents of my `CentOS-Base.repo` are:

```
> # CentOS-Base.repo
> #
> # The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
> # update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
> # geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
> # unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
> #
> # If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the
> # remarked out baseurl= line instead.
> #
> #
> 
> [base] name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
> mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
> #baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/ gpgcheck=1 gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
> 
> #released updates [updates] name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
> #baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
> gpgcheck=1 gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
> 
> #additional packages that may be useful [extras] name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
> mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
> #baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/ gpgcheck=1 gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
> 
> #additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages [centosplus] name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
> mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus&infra=$infra
> #baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
> gpgcheck=1 enabled=0
> gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

And the contents of `/etc/yum.conf` are:

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=23&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release


#  This is the default, if you make this bigger yum won't see if the metadata
# is newer on the remote and so you'll "gain" the bandwidth of not having to
# download the new metadata and "pay" for it by yum not having correct
# information.
#  It is esp. important, to have correct metadata, for distributions like
# Fedora which don't keep old packages around. If you don't like this checking
# interupting your command line usage, it's much better to have something
# manually check the metadata once an hour (yum-updatesd will do this).
# metadata_expire=90m

# PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo
# in /etc/yum.repos.d
```

How can I make `yum update` work again???

Comment: maybe you try to set a specific repo server, [see here](https://serverfault.com/questions/365106/centos-yum-specify-mirror)

Comment: That looks like it might be some sort of local network problem. I am able to access `http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?repo=os&arch=x86_64&release=7` without a problem. Do you run into the same problem with any other machines on the same network?

Comment: @Pathros  `Trying 2001:1b48:203::4:10...` do you intend to connect via IPv6 ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, using a static configured IP address. My resolution to get this to work was configuring DNS in the interface conf file.

"vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/$InterfaceName$"

I added in the following lines

```
DNS1=Internal Server IP
DNS2=8.8.8.8
```

This seemed to work for me.